# Gap between actual computation time and expected one in R

Tags: r, iteration, computation, elapsedtime

I have an iterative algorithm which repeats the same procedure based on previously updated parameters, and try to estimate the elapsed time for the whole algorithm.

Therefore, I measure a computation time (say, `time1iter`) for a single iteration, and estimate overall time by multiplying it with total iteration time (`nIter * time1iter`).

However, it has been found that huge difference appears between my estimate and actual time. For example, the estimated time is about 8 mins, but it takes less than 6 mins.

I wonder

1. what has caused this gap in general, and
2. how I can correctly estimate the elapsed time for iterative procedures.

I attach a toy example where you can find this "overestimation".

```
size <- 1000
nIter <- 100

## A single iteration
s_time <- Sys.time()
tmp <- matrix(rnorm(size^2), size, size)
ss <- 0
for(i in 1:size){
  for(j in 1:size){
    ss <- ss + tmp[i,j]
  }
}
time1iter <- difftime(Sys.time(), s_time, units = "secs")
cat(sprintf("Expected time for %d iterations is %3.f secs\n", 
            nIter, time1iter * nIter))

## Main iterations
s_time <- Sys.time()
for(iter in 1:nIter){
  tmp <- matrix(rnorm(size^2), size, size)
  ss <- 0
  for(i in 1:size){
    for(j in 1:size){
      ss <- ss + tmp[i,j]
    }
  }
}
cat(sprintf("Actual elapsed time is %.3f secs\n", 
            difftime(Sys.time(), s_time, units = "secs")))
```

A result that I had is

> Expected time for 100 iterations is  17 secs
>
> Actual elapsed time is 12.948 secs

Answer (score 2):

If we run the loop several times with increasing numbers of iterations, we get a pretty linear relation between time and number of iterations:

```
res = data.frame(nIter = seq(1,101,10), time=NA)
for (ni in 1:10){
  nIter <- res[ni, 'nIter']
  s_time <- Sys.time()
  for(iter in 1:nIter){
    tmp <- matrix(rnorm(size^2), size, size)
    ss <- 0
    for(i in 1:size){
      for(j in 1:size){
        ss <- ss + tmp[i,j]
      }
    }
  }
  res[ni, 'time'] <- difftime(Sys.time(), s_time, units = "secs")
}

library(ggplot2)
ggplot(res, aes(nIter, time)) +
  geom_smooth()
```

[image]

The small intercept is related things like overhead of interpreting the loop, getting and printing the time. In other words, this seems to behave much as one would expect

```
lm(time ~ nIter, data = res)    
Coefficients:
(Intercept)        nIter  
   0.009067     0.165585
```

Comment: This answers one of questions in my mind! I do appreciate your efforts to deliver it elegantly =) Would you able to answer why this happens and how we can estimate correct (total) elapsed time?

Comment: You can use the linear model to estimate time.  On my computer, time = 0.009 + 0.165 * nIter.  You'd need to run the same code on your machine to get local timings

Comment: I think it is an ad-hoc solution, which means the estimates would change if your code changes. In other words, I want to estimate it whenever I run my algorithm, not only for a single case.